# rpm command giving error while asking for information

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I have one package `VAB-6.1.0.500-0.x86_64`. When I installed this on machine and run command `rpm -q VAB`, it is showing package VAB not installed . And if i run command `rpm -q VAB-` it is showing `VAB-6.1.0.500-0.x86_64` which is expected ?

Why so? Is rpm needs fullname to search? Is there anything that is related to spec file?

I have tried on other machines where asking only `rpm -q VAB` is working fine. 
The machine on which rpm giving error was also working fine with `rpm -q VAB` previously.

Comment: loading keyring from rpmdb is failing

Comment: what is keyring ? If i sign rpm ,then will it be removed ?

Answer (score 0):

The command "rpm -q VAB" will display what you want.

Try "rpm --rebuilddb" first. Then try "rpm -qvv VAB" or "rpm -qa | grep VAB".

Comment: i dont want to rebuilddb . `rpm -qa | VAB` is working fine but `rpm -q VAB` should also work . The strengh thing is `rpm -q VAB-` is working . Note hyphen(-)

Comment: Queries are resolved against the rpmdb. You have differing results with one rpmdb than others, which indicates that there is something different. Try rebuilding the indices rather than trying to infer what is different about "rpm -q VAB-" vs "rpm -q VAB"